# Can someone explain empty parameters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, parameters, parameter-passing

Every time I've seen empty parameters, it appeared in a method like this:

```
def method_name(arguments)
  #stuff to be executed
end
```

And then a method is called. Now I've come across this:

```
x = something()
```

What am I looking at? I am aware it is a variable, but what is the empty part?

Comment: What is a variable? What empty part?

Comment: `method_name != something` ???

Comment: In Ruby, `something` could be a variable or a method. Ruby determines which it is. `something()` forces it to be looked up as a method.

Comment: Most of the time, parenthesis are optional. One notable exception is `super` vs. `super()`

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a situation where you have a variable `something` and a method `something`.  Whenever you refer `something()` you are referring to the method.

```
def something
  "Java"
end

something = "Ruby"

a = something #=> value of a is "Ruby"
a = something() #=> value of a is "Java" # got from method
```

Comment: It's really irregular to see methods called like `something()` to dodge what would otherwise be a variable reference. More common is `self.something` to be explicit. You're right, though, that does force a method call. Normally it's a bad idea to have methods and variables with the same names, so it's best to avoid this by calling them something different.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby method parameters are very flexible. According to the method definition, the parameters that are given in the call can be passed directly, defaulted if absent, or compressed to a single Array parameter.

This short program demonstrates. The way parameter checking works is

- Parameters supplied in the call are first allocated to all the individual non-defaulted parameters in the method definition, from first to last.
- If there are insufficient actual parameters to match all non-defaulted formal parameters, a `wrong number of arguments (N for M) (ArgumentError)` is raised.
- If any actual parameters remain then they are then allocated to all *defaulted* parameters, from first to last.
- If any actual parameters *still* remain, then they will be bundled into an array and allocated to a *splat* parameter, if one has been defined.
- If any actual parameters *still* remain, and no splat parameters have been defined, a `wrong number of arguments (N for M) (ArgumentError)` is raised.

This program demonstrates some of those situations. The commented lines would raise the error described.

```
def method_name(arguments)
  puts "method_name(#{arguments})"
end

def something()
  puts 'something()'
end

def something_else(param = 99)
  puts "something_else(#{param})"
end

def something_more(param = 99, *rest)
  puts "something_else(#{param}, #{rest})"
end

#method_name()
method_name(1)

#something(1)
something()

something_else()
something_else(42)

something_more()
something_more(1)
something_more(1, 2)
```

**output**

```
method_name(1)
something()
something_else(99)
something_else(42)
something_more(99, [])
something_more(1, [])
something_more(1, [2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, parentheses are optional, so in your example, calling `method_name` is the equivalent of calling `method_name()`, however your method requires an argument.  Perhaps this would illustrate it better:

```
def method_name(arguments={})
  #do stuff
end
```

This method has an optional parameter of a hash.  You can call this method with any of: `method_name`, `method_name()`, or `method_name(argument1: "something")`